# Primary Keys and Indexes - Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, primary-key

I have a table which contains over 1 million records. There are no keys defined on the table.
However we do have clustered and non-clustered index defined.

I want to know if there will be actually a performance improvement when I do a `SELECT` query and include the columns where we have index created in the `WHERE` clause?

Is having primary / unique key a must to leverage the true benefits of Indexes?

Table details:

- 260 columns
- No Keys
- No identity column defined.
- No rowguidcol column defined.
- 1 clustered index and 1 non clustered index

Query:

```
select * 
from employee(nolock)
where employeeID = '15' and employeeType = 'FT'
```

Comment: Please provide the table layout and an example of the queries you are trying to run.

Comment: 260 columns
No Keys
No identity column defined.
No rowguidcol column defined.
1 clustered index and 1 non clustered index

select * from employee(nolock)
where employeeID = '15' and employeeType = 'FT'

Comment: What are the column and data-types used in the clustered/nonclustered index?

Comment: When using `SELECT * ` you're always running the risk that the query optimizer will just use a table scan / clustered index scan instead of doing a lot of seeks and key lookups. If you would be using `SELECT col1, col2, ..., colN ` then there's a chance that you could create a **covering index** that would contain all columns needed to satisfy this query and thus speed things up **significantly**

Answer (score 0):

Personally based on my experience the clustered index is best when it's narrow, unique and non-changing. The smaller the clustered key (non-unique clustered indexes add a 4 byte "uniquifier") the better because it creates a denser leaf page on the subsequent non-clustered indexes.

Assuming you currently have a non-unique clustered index on an integer (assuming employeeID is an integer), then the size of each key is effectively doubled do to the uniquifier (4 from the integer and 4 from the uniquifier).

The difference between a non-unique/unique clustered index would be the non-clustered leaf rows fitting, respectively, 1000 and 2000 rows to a page. A denser non-clustered leaf page means traversing the index levels faster as well as saving on disk space (1000000 rows at 4byte saved a row amounts to roughly 3 gigs per non-clustered index).

A lot of this is based on assumptions on your table.

TLDR: A narrow clustered index key is best; make it a primary key to enforce uniqueness and prevent a wasteful 4byte uniquifier.